# How to clip PowerPoint graphics using Apache POI with XSLF API

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to convert a Eclipse Draw2D Figure to a PowerPoint page by implementing `org.eclipse.draw2d.Graphics` with Apache POI's XSLF API.

Apache POI's HSLF API supports a similar approach for AWT drawing, implementing `java.awt.Graphics2D` with HSLF class `org.apache.poi.hslf.model.PPGraphics2D`.

The base graphics classes for both AWT and Draw2D provide methods to clip subsequent drawing. This is highly useful when drawing part of a larger scene.

The Apache POI implementation of the AWT graphics methods to set the clipping region is to log a warning. This suggests that it might not be feasible to clip arbitrary drawing in a PowerPoint page. So too does the apparent lack of controls for setting such clipping within the PowerPoint application itself.

**Questions:**

A) Is clipping feasible in PowerPoint documents?

B) If so, how can clipping be requested through Apache POI?'

C) If not, what are possible workarounds?

**Notes:**

In my case, I have adjacent columns that each need to be clipped. Laying big background-colored rectangles over the margins isn't sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at `org.apache.poi.sl.draw.SLGraphics` - I might remove the PPGraphics2D class in the not so far future.

A) I think it's not such an big issue, I've did some rudimentary clipping in [Graphics2d context for JasperReports](https://github.com/kiwiwings/pptx-shape-exporter/blob/master/Pptx-Shape-Exporter/src/main/java/de/kiwiwings/jasperreports/exporter/PptxGraphics2D.java)

B) maybe via opening a [feature request](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=POI&component=SL%20Common) ;)

C) The workaround is to extend SLGraphics (preferably) or PPGraphics2D, but you basically would need to include the clipping in all drawing calls, i.e. clip all shapes.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful guidance. We're mostly using rectangular clipping, and that seems like it would be easy to hand-compute for polygons. Not so sure about text yet. I'm considering the possibility of throwing up my hands whenever there's any clipping or scaling and adding a bitmapped image to the document instead of something vector-based.

Comment: You can convert text to shapes (also included in the linked Graphics2D class) and use `Area.intersect ()` to clip arbitrary shapes.